# How do I say "Nowadays (in the previous year)"?

Tags: expressions

I need a way of saying "These days" / "Nowadays", but referring to the previous year.

Because what I've come up with seems very unnatural and broken to me.

- These days last year, I had no clue what would happen in a year's time.
- Last year nowadays, .... (This one sounds awful to me, honestly)

For clarity: I want to be able to say "Around these months/dates of the previous year" without the definitive words like "month" or "date", but with vague words like "these days" or "nowadays".

Comment: What's commonly said and probably readily understood is "last year at this time".

Comment: Or even, "A year ago".

Comment: I think the idea could include some form of "yesteryear"

Comment: @KristinaLopez Or even *This time last year...*

Comment: That's better, @WS2...more succinct! :-)

Comment: If you want "vague words" then *a year ago these days* might be what you want. But most English speakers don't say such an expression. We commonly say the expressions that Kristina, WS2 and Andrew have contributed.

Answer (score 2):

"At this time last year, I ..."

Comment: "around" may be better than "at" - less specific, just as easily understood (by me, anyway)

Comment: Yep, "around" is just fine and is less specific, as you said.

Answer (score -1):

Those days during last year;
Those days in the first-half of last year;
Those days in the second-half of last year